# Replacing positive, negative, and zero values by 1, -1, and 0 respectively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe(100,000 obs) with 11 columns.

I'm trying to assign `df['trade_sign']` values based on the `df['diff']` (which is a pd.series object of integer values)

If diff is positive, then trade_sign = 1 
if diff is negative, then trade_sign = -1 
if diff is 0, then trade_sign = 0

What I've tried so far:

```py
pos['trade_sign'] = (pos['trade_sign']>0) <br>
pos['trade_sign'].replace({False: -1, True: 1}, inplace=True)
```

But this obviously doesn't take into account 0 values. 
I also tried for loops with if conditions but that didn't work.

Essentially, how do I fix my .replace function to take account of diff values of 0.

Ideally, I'd prefer a solution that uses numpy over for loops with if conditions.

[image: dataframe]

Comment: There is a function ‘np.sign’ that you can apply directly to the diffed column.

Comment: You can use the function `df['trade_sign'] = np.select([df['diff'] >= 0 , df['diff'] < 0], [1, -1])`

Comment: Were you helped by any of the answers provided? If so, please accept one so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `sign` function in numpy:

```py
df["trade_sign"] = np.sign(df["diff"])
```

If you want integers,

```py
df["trade_sign"] = np.sign(df["diff"]).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```py
pos['trade_sign'] = (pos['diff'] > 0) * 1 + (pos['diff'] < 0) * -1
```

The `boolean` results of the element-wise `>` and `<` comparisons automatically get converted to `int` in order to allow multiplication with `1` and `-1`, respectively.

This sample input and test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
pos = pd.DataFrame({'diff':[-9,0,9,-8,0,8,-7-6-5,4,3,2,0]})
pos['trade_sign'] = (pos['diff'] > 0) * 1 + (pos['diff'] < 0) * -1
print(pos)
```

... gives this output:

```
    diff  trade_sign
0     -9          -1
1      0           0
2      9           1
3     -8          -1
4      0           0
5      8           1
6    -18          -1
7      4           1
8      3           1
9      2           1
10     0           0
```

**UPDATE**: In addition to the solution above, as well as some of the other excellent ideas in other answers, you can use numpy `where`:

```py
pos['trade_sign'] = np.where(pos['diff'] > 0, 1, np.where(pos['diff'] < 0, -1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    a = [-1 if df['diff'].values[i] < 0 else 1 for i in range(len(df['diff'].values))]
    df['trade_sign'] = a
```